# Array does not return expected value

Tags: c#, .net

I need in C # to create a list that returns the 10 Brazilian states with the largest territory, but I'm not getting the correct amount. 
This list must return the following results:
Top 10 largest states in Brazil: Amazonas - 1,570,745 km²; Pará - 1,247,689 km²; Mato Grosso - 903,357 km²; Minas Gerais - 588,528 km²; Bahia - 564,692 km²; Mato Grosso do Sul - 358,158 km²; Goiás - 340,086 km²; Maranhão - 331,983 km²; Rio Grande do Sul - 282,062 km²; Tocantins - 277,620 km²
Thankful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Brazil
    {
        public class Country
        {
            public State[] Top10StatesByArea()
            {
                string[,] BrazilianStates = {

                    {"AC","Acre","164123,040"},
                    {"AL","Alagoas","27778,506"},
                    {"AP","Amapá","142828,521"},
                    {"AM","Amazonas","1559159,148"},
                    {"BA","Bahia","564773,177"},
                    {"CE","Ceará","148920,472"},
                    {"DF","Distrito Federal","5779,999"},
                    {"ES","Espírito Santo","46095,583"},
                    {"GO","Goiás","340111,783"},
                    {"MA","Maranhão","331937,450"},
                    {"MT","Mato Grosso","903366,192"},
                    {"MS","Mato Grosso do Sul","357145,532"},
                    {"MG","Minas Gerais","586522.122"},
                    {"PA","Pará","1247954,666"},
                    {"PB","Paraíba","56585,000"},
                    {"PR","Paraná","199307,922"},
                    {"PE","Pernambuco","98311,616"},
                    {"PI","Piauí","251577,738"},
                    {"RJ","Rio de Janeiro","43780,172"},
                    {"RN","Rio Grande do Norte","52811,047"},
                    {"RS","Rio Grande do Sul","281730,223"},
                    {"RO","Rondônia","237590,547"},
                    {"RR","Roraima","224300,506"},
                    {"SC","Santa Catarina","95736,165"},
                    {"SP","São Paulo","248222,362"},
                    {"SE","Sergipe","21915,116"},
                    {"TO","Tocantins","277720,520"},

                };

                int states = (BrazilianStates.Length / BrazilianStates.GetLength(1));

                for (int a = 0; a < states; a++)
                {
                    for (int b = a + 1; b < states; b++)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToDouble(BrazilianStates[b, BrazilianStates.Rank]) > 
                           (Convert.ToDouble(BrazilianStates[a, BrazilianStates.Rank])))
                        {
                            for (int c = 0; c <= BrazilianStates.Rank; c++)
                            {
                                string[,] aux = { { "", "", ""} };
                                aux[0, c] = BrazilianStates[a, c];
                                BrazilianStates[a, c] = BrazilianStates[b, c];
                                BrazilianStates[b, c] = aux[0, c];
                            }
                            Convert.ToString(BrazilianStates);

                        }
                    }
                }
                State[] ArrayBrazilianStates =
                {
                    new State(BrazilianStates[0, 1], BrazilianStates[0,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[1, 1], BrazilianStates[1,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[2, 1], BrazilianStates[2,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[3, 1], BrazilianStates[3,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[4, 1], BrazilianStates[4,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[5, 1], BrazilianStates[5,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[6, 1], BrazilianStates[6,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[7, 1], BrazilianStates[7,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[8, 1], BrazilianStates[8,0]),
                    new State(BrazilianStates[9, 1], BrazilianStates[9,0]),
                };
                return ArrayBrazilianStates;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than using a multi dimensional array, I'd suggest creating a `Region` class to store the `ShortName`, `LongName` and `Area`. Then have a `List<Region>` Then `OrderByDescending` the `Area` and `Take` the 10 records you want.

Comment: Yep, @mjwills solution is exactly how I would achieve your goal. Then use `Take(10)` to get your top 10 values. (thanks mjwills for the tip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing the following:

```
(string code, string name, double area)[] BrazilianStates =
{
    ("AC", "Acre", 164123.040),
    // etc
};

(string code, string name, double area)[] top10 =
    BrazilianStates
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.area)
        .Take(10)
        .ToArray();
```

Note that I changed the 2 dimension array into a single dimensional, strongly-typed, array of tuples.